# Show that the set of global minimizers of $f$ is a convex set. If there can be only one global minimizer, how?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm studying non linear optimization and there's the following exercise:

> Suppose that $f$ is a convex function. Show that the set of global
>   minimizers of $f$ is a convex set.

A point $x^*$ is a global minimizer if $f(x^*)\le f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. So how is it possible for $2$ or more to exist?

Comment: Singletons are convex sets.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist That wasn't the question.

Comment: @amsmath I know, that’s why I wrote a comment, instead of extending it to an answer.

Comment: What if there are points $x^{(1)}$ and $x^{(2)}$ that both have the same optimal objective value?  Note that the question didn't say that $f$ was strictly convex, just that it was convex.  Can you come up with an example?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist What I meant is: your statement is not related to the question. OP thinks that the claim implies there only exists one global minimzer.

Comment: @amsmath Of course it’s related. The OP’s wording suggests that convex sets must contain at least two distinct elements. They may not necessarily think that, but it’s probably useful to dispel that notion just in case. At any rate, I struggle to see why you’re quibbling over a comment that was never intended to be an answer, and hence not posted as such.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist "The OP’s wording suggests that convex sets must contain at least two distinct elements" And I was pointing you to the fact that this is not suggested by OP's wording. Read it again. "At any rate, I struggle to see why you’re quibbling over a comment that was never intended to be an answer, and hence not posted as such." Because you didn't get OP's point.

Comment: @amsmath and I point you to my exact previous comment. Read it again.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist OP's wording suggests that they knew that a singleton is a convex set.

Comment: @amsmath you’ve already said that. There’s no point in repeating yourself, nor is there any in mine doing the same. Let’s agree to disagree.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Ok, I agree. ;o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be a convex function and assume that $x_1,x_2$ are global minimizers (that is, $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\le f(x),\forall x$. It follows by definition that, for all $t\in [0,1],$

$$f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\le tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2) \le tf(x)+(1-t)f(x)=f(x).$$ This shows that

$$f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\le f(x)$$ from where we get that $tx_1+(1-t)x_2$ is also a global minimizer and thus we have shown that the set of global minimizers is convex.

If the function is strictly convex then there is only one global minimizer but it is not the case if we consider convex functions.

For example

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 &\quad \text{if}\quad x\le 0\\ x^2 &\quad \text{if}\quad x>0 \end{cases}$$ is a convex function and the set of global minimizers is $(-\infty,0].$

Answer (score 0):

If there are 2 global minimizers, the statement in particular implies that there are infinitely many - namely also all those on the line segment between the two minimizers. So, there is either exactly one global minimizer or infinitely many.

Comment: The OP asks “how is it possible for $2$ or more to exist?”. Stating that there is either only one or infinitely many does not explain how the latter is possible.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I partially agree. However, I interpreted OP in the way that they understood that it's not possible to have exactly 2, 3, or just finitely many global minimizers. This answer is a confirmation of their thinking.